# background-color problems in css

Tags: html, css, background-color

I encountered a problem when writing this code.

```
 <body>
    <header>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="sayfa_ismi"><h1>PAGE TİTLE</h1></div>
            <nav class="menues">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="home"><p>Home Page</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="galery.html" class="galery"><p>Galery</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="stry.html" class="stry"><p>Story</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="herkes_nerede.html"class="where"><p>Where are the people</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="iletisim.html" class="iletisim"><p>Contact</p></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
      </div>
    </header>



    </div>
  </body>
```

in CSS

```
header{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

/*************************** title position ************************************/
.sayfa_ismi{
  text-align: center;
}
/*************************** menue position************************************/
nav li{
  display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 8% 0 0;
  }

nav{
  margin: 0 0 0 15%;
}

/*************************** menu links************************************/
.menues a:link{
  color:rgb(255,255,255);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menues a:hover{
  color:blue;
  background-color:white;
}

.menues a:visited{
  color: blue;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;

}
/***** header font type and background color *****************************/
header{
  background-color: rgb(59, 113, 255);
  font-family: 'Andada', serif;
  font-size: 110%;
}
```

I want Header's background color to be rgb(59, 113, 255) and I want the background color to be white when we come to link but don't.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you inspected the log element to see if the CSS is being overwritten? Have you tried using the !important css declaration inline or locally to override cascading styles within your backgounrd-color: css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove `p` tag inside `a` tag.

Here is an updated fiddle: [fiddle link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/teutakoraqi/50vsvx5e/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.menues ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

.menues {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.menues li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menues a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.menues a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}


/*************************** title position ************************************/

.sayfa_ismi {
  text-align: center;
}


/*************************** menue position************************************/

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 8% 0 0;
}


/***** header font type and background color *****************************/

header {
  background-color: rgb(59, 113, 255);
  font-family: 'Andada', serif;
  font-size: 110%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="sayfa_ismi">
        <h1>PAGE TİTLE</h1>
      </div>
      <nav class="menues">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="home">Home Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="galery.html" class="galery">Galery</a></li>
          <li><a href="stry.html" class="stry">Story</a></li>
          <li><a href="herkes_nerede.html" class="where">Where are the people</a></li>
          <li><a href="iletisim.html" class="iletisim">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, I understand some good point.I have another question How can I keep the background white when it visits?

Comment: Using this properties `a:visited {
  background-color: white;
}`    moreover you can follow this link https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/visited/

Answer (score 0):

this code will do

```html
<body>
<header id="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="sayfa_ismi">
      <h1>PAGE TITLE</h1>
    </div>
    <nav class="menues">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a onmouseover="linkHover()" onmouseout="linkmouseout()" href="index.html" class="home">
            <p>Home Page</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onmouseover="linkHover()" onmouseout="linkmouseout()" href="galery.html" class="galery">
            <p>Galery</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onmouseover="linkHover()" onmouseout="linkmouseout()" href="stry.html" class="stry">
            <p>Story</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onmouseover="linkHover()" onmouseout="linkmouseout()" href="herkes_nerede.html" class="where">
            <p>Where are the people</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onmouseover="linkHover()" onmouseout="linkmouseout()" href="iletisim.html" class="iletisim">
            <p>Contact</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<script>
  var header = document.getElementById("header");
  function linkHover() {
    header.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  }
  function linkmouseout() {
    header.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(59, 113, 255)";
  }

</script>


</div>
</body>
```